# Can we put simple html in MVC2 instead of Razor?

Tags: asp.net, razor, web, asp.net-mvc-2

Can I put simple html, and make simple master pages in MVC 2 (Asp.net) instead of RAZOR syntax? According to many books and articles we should use RAZOR's syntax but I'm not used to it so can I put simple html and make master pages and then importing it etc.?

Comment: I suggest you should try first yourself. Post any question if you face any problem in doing that.

Comment: sure, i did but it gives no proper output, shows html tags on browser's page but works good in old html web forms :/

Comment: When the application is created for the first time, it asks wether u want it to have Razor engine or Web forms engine

so try to create new application with web forms engine, then u may get good old master pages

Comment: it doesn't give me this option :(

Comment: using VS 2010 ultimate + MVC 2
begginner i am